# How do I distribute datasets between multiple GPUs in Tensorflow 2?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, distributed

I'm trying to understand how to use multiple gpus to train a model on data too large for the GPU memory. Using `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` seems to copy the full data set to each GPU. What I'm hoping to do is to send a subset of the full dataset to each GPU (2 or 4 gpus) and use MirroredStrategy to reconcile parameter updates on each epoch.

`MirroredStrategy.distribute_datasets_from_function()` looks promising.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy#distribute_datasets_from_function

Problem details:
A fairly complicated multimodal NN with ~200k parameters synthesizing many text, transactional, and structured inputs and with multiple regression and probabilistic outputs. I'm looking at moving development from a single GPU with 24gb memory to cloud compute with multiple 16gb cards on a single node.

The input and targets are currently dictionaries of numpy arrays. I'm hoping for a toy example converting those dictionaries into a distributed data set through to training with different subsets of the full data set assigned to each GPU.

I attempted this:

```py
def build_model(**model_params):
    '''
    Builds a model from model_params
    '''
    return tf.keras.Model(
       inputs = [MY_INPUT_TENSORS],
       output = [MY_OUTPUT_TENSORS])

distributed_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

with distributed_strategy.scope():
    train_model = build_model(**model_params)

    train_model.compile(...)


train_model.fit(X_dict, y_dict)
```

This runs on a 50% sample of the data, but returns OOM on the full sample on 2 GPUs. The full data set appears to be copied to each of the 2 16gb GPUs available. The same model runs with a 100% sample on a single 24gb GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it working with `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` and `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy.experimental_distribute_dataset()`:

```py
#Data exists in the form of dictionaries of large numpy arrays
x_train, y_train, x_validation, y_validation = {},{},{},{}

#Create tensorflow datasets using CPU / system memory
with tf.device("CPU"):
    train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
    valid = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_validation, y_validation))

batch_size = 1024
epochs = 30

distributed_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
num_gpu = distributed_strategy.num_replicas_in_sync

#Create a distributed dataset from the tensorflow datasets.
#The data gets streamed to the GPUs, so shuffling, repetition / epoch, and batch
#size need to be manually specified
train = train.shuffle(100*batch_size).repeat(epochs).batch(num_gpu * batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
train_dist = distributed_strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(train)

valid = valid.repeat(epochs).batch(num_gpu * batch_size, drop_remainder=True)

#Build and compile the model
with distributed_strategy.scope():
    train_model = build_model(**model_params)
    train_model.compile(
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = learning_rate),
        loss = losses,
        loss_weights = weights    )

#Train the model. steps_per_epoch and validation_steps need to be specified.
train_model.fit(
    train_dist,
    validation_data = valid,
    epochs = epochs,
    steps_per_epoch = int(len(train)//epochs),
    validation_steps = int(len(valid)//epochs),
    use_multiprocessing = True,
    verbose = 1,
)
```